# How To Choose Which Devices Show Up in "Eject Media" in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, media, eject, safely-remove-hardware

My "Safely Remove Hardware and Eject Media" menu looks like this:

[image]

The "USB 2.0 BILLBOARD" refers to the displays on the CPU's integrated graphics over the USB-C connection. I'm not completely sure about the other two, but device manager is showing them as:

[image]
[image]

Generally, I use this menu to eject flash drives and other portable media, but now I risk accidentally hitting one of these every time I want to use the menu.

Is there any way to prevent these specific items from showing up under safely eject media? It doesn't make sense to me why they would be ejectable, and I definitely don't want to accidentally eject them while the PC is running.

This is Windows 10 21H2 and an AMD Ryzen 7950X CPU. I am using 7 monitors total. There is a GTX 1080 TI discrete GPU in the system, with three 1440p displays plugged into it. There are four 1080p displays using the integrated graphics.